# convert string to DateTime in C# with EDT at the end

Tags: c#, datetime

i have to parse this string below into a datetime object in C#:

```
Wed, 13 Apr 2011 07:11:04 -0400 (EDT)
```

what is the simplest way of doing this?

I understand there is DateTime.Parse and DateTime.ParseExact but i am trying to figure out what the custom format syntax would be for this above.

Comment: Besides [`DateTime.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx) method?

Comment: Have you tried passing it into the constructor of a new DateTime object?

Comment: wow you've asked a lot of questions on this site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) and pass in a custom format.
Something like:

```
var parsed = DateTime.ParseExact("Wed, 13 Apr 2011 07:11:04 -0400 (EDT)", 
                                 "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", null);
```

**Note**
Time zone abbreviations are not supported as there is no official designation of them and they are sometimes ambiguous.
You should strip this from the input to parse the above. You could look at parsing that yourself if you know what the possible values will be.

Comment: basically my question is what would the custom format syntax be to parse the above.

Comment: i don't see this overload.  all overload seem to require a FormatProvider as well

Comment: @ooo you can pass `null` or `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` if you don't really want to pass a format provider. - Sorry entered code from memory.